# JavaScript XMLHttpRequest, кросс-доменные http запросы

Tags: javascript

С моей страницы сайта, нужно сделать http запрос на другой сайт и получить ответ на него.

Только изучаю ajax запросы, и в какой то статье прочитал такое "ajax запрос можно делать только на адреса с тем же протоколом, доменом, портом, что и текущая страница."

это значет, это реализовать нельзя?

Я пробовал так:

var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("get", "http://yandex.ru", true);
x.onreadystatechange = function() {alert(x.responseText);}
x.send(null);

Через алерт я бы хотел видеть html код яндекса.

Как это можно реализовать?

Может как то прокси использовать, если из выше написанного отрывка из статьи, написано что можно делать запросы только с тем же доменом.

Объясните пожалуйста, если я что то не правильно понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно читать "какие-то" статьи, пользуйтесь проверенными источниками информации: [Кросс-доменный XMLHttpRequest](http://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain)